# Replacing and trimming messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to toLowerCase, replace and then trim that replace so something like
`Hello [- the re _- wo rl d.`
will turn into a string with no spaces or punctuation like
`hellothereworld`

I'm using this

```
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase()
    let originalMessage = msg.split(" ");
    let removePunctuation = originalMessage.toString().replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    let checkMessage = removePunctuation.toString().trim();
```

then this to filter the message:

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkMessage.length; i++) {
    if(allowed.includes(checkMessage[i])) {
        continue;
    }
    if(curse.includes(checkMessage[i])) {
        const filterViolation = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setTitle('Filter Violation')
            .setDescription(`${rule} **Profanity.** \n${ifcont}\n${ifmistake}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(copyright);
        message.delete()
        message.author.send(filterViolation)
        message.channel.send(msgvio).then(msg => {msg.delete(15000)})
        logger.write(logviolation)
    }
//More code
}
```

<sup>Thanks to Tarazed for the help with the filter in general.</sup>

But when I type any message that goes against the filter, nothing happens and no errors are thrown in the console. Any ideas on what I did wrong?

**New Code:**

```
let checkMessage = message.content.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w ]/g,"");

    console.log(checkMessage);

    // let checkMessage = msg.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < checkMessage.length; i++) {
    if(checkMessage.includes(allowed[i])) {
        continue;
    }
//--------------------------------------- CURSE
    if(checkMessage.includes(curse[i])) {
        const filterViolation = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setTitle('Filter Violation')
            .setDescription(`${rule} **Profanity.** \n${ifcont}\n${ifmistake}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(copyright);
        message.delete()
        message.author.send(filterViolation)
        message.channel.send(msgvio).then(msg => {msg.delete(15000)})
        logger.write(logviolation)
    }
}
```

It logs the check message correctly `console.log(checkMessage);` but it doesn't go through the filter, neither allowed or unallowed.

[image: Message sent]
[image: Output in console]

It logs the message correctly but the word violates the filter, but nothing is done.

**New Code 2:**

```
if(curse.some(word => checkMessage.includes(word) && !allowed.some(allow => allow.includes(word) && checkMessage.includes(allow)))) {
        const filterViolation = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setTitle('Filter Violation')
            .setDescription(`${rule} **Profanity.** \n${ifcont}\n${ifmistake}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(copyright);
        message.delete()
        message.author.send(filterViolation)
        message.channel.send(msgvio).then(msg => {msg.delete(15000)})
        logger.write(logviolation)
        return;
    }
```

Comment: are you, at any point, logging `checkMessage` to make sure it's what you expect...?

Comment: Yes I am, and it when i type "t - e st" it logs "test"

Comment: Is that what you are expecting? As I see it now you loop through each character (in `checkMessage`) to check whether it is in the allowed characters but what is the point of that if the "bad" characters have already been filtered out?

Comment: You can simplify your regex for replacing non-alphanumeric characters to `/[\W]/`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm expecting it to turn something like that random string into one with no spaces and no punctuation. But it's also supposed to check and see if that final message violates the filter in any way, but it doesn't. Also Ed Lucas, I tried putting that in instead of the long thing and it spammed with Violations non-stop. 
`originalMessage.toString().replace(/[\W]/);`

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 you didn't tell it what to replace with, that code will just replace the first character with `undefined` - please see my answer for correct usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current problem is that you're iterating over literally just a string like `"test"` and checking if each letter is a curse word.

That is, `checkMessage[0]` will be `'t'`, `checkMessage[1]` will be `'e'`, etc. I'm guessing no single character will match anything in your `curse` or even `allowed` array.

You can get rid of the loop entirely and simply check `if(curse.includes(checkMessage))`, the entire message... but be wary this may easily return false positives. Heaven forbid someone sends a message like `"it was a nice pic until i looked closer"` and `pic until` put together triggers a certain c-word in your filter.

Anyway, I'd like to also point out that your code for stripping out spaces and punctuation does some rather strange things. I'll comment what I expect to be happening at each stage. Assume an input message of `" Hello - world. "`

```
let originalMessage = msg                    //" hello - world. "
                       .split(" ");          //["", "hello", "-", "world.", ""]
let removePunctuation = originalMessage
                         .toString()         //",hello,-,world.," (why even split?)
                         .replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,""); //"helloworld"
let checkMessage = removePunctuation
                    .toString() //"helloworld" (does nothing ever)
                    .trim();    //"helloworld" (does nothing ever)
```

You can achieve the same thing very easily by using the regex class `\W` which matches all non-word characters:

```
let checkMessage = message.content.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g,""); //"helloworld"
```

---

It looks like there's still issues related to the loop. I suggest using `Array#some` to test if the message contains any curse words:

```
let checkMessage = message.content.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w ]/g,"");

if(curse.some(word =>                //search through the curse words
     checkMessage.includes(word) &&  //if message has this curse word
     !allowed.some(allow =>          //and there's no allowed word which:
       allow.includes(word) &&       //1. contains this curse word
       checkMessage.includes(allow)  //2. is in the message
     )
  )) {
  //then send violation
}
```

Comment: That did the trick for the part with removing punctuation, but like Ed Lucas said using `/[^\w ]/g,""` doesn't do spaces. I took into consideration your example about "pic until" and it's a very valid point. So I have that, but it still does not run through the whole filter.

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 so it's still not working? if so, I suggest editing in your new code to the question along with any console output, it should be working with these changes

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 see my edit. I may have misunderstood the purpose of your `allow` array, but I assume it is words which contain curse words as substrings but should not trigger a violation. if this is not correct, let me know.

Comment: Yes that's correct, changed it to that, now it sends 4 violations. sorry if this is annoying to you. Here's a picture of the error [link](https://gyazo.com/148778a66d1e4ef35aa5e06c0d651c1b)

Comment: @PrinceBunBun981 It looks like you still have it in a loop. It should no longer be in a loop of any kind. Please remove any loops other than the .some() and make sure to `return` after sending the violation message.

Comment: Edited the code, is that correct? It seems to be working well for me. Added the return to the last bit of the violation.

Comment: Someone tested it for me and it seems to have the same problem, not sure why though. It sends it 4 times, but this time there's nothing in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208686/discussion-between-princebunbun981-and-klaycon).

Answer (score 1):

Since `checkMessage` is a string, your `for` loop is looping over and testing individual characters.

For example:

```js
let checkMessage = "hellothereworld";
for (let i = 0; i < checkMessage.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkMessage[i]);
}
```

Perhaps you'd rather keep the spaces in your string and operate on individual words:

```js
let originalMessage = "Hello [-the world"


// Use regex that keeps spaces
let removePunctuation = originalMessage.toString().replace(/[^\w ]/g,"");
let checkMessage = removePunctuation.toString().trim();

// Split into words
let messageArray = checkMessage.split(' ');

// Loop over words
for (let i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(messageArray[i]);
}
```